# apache2 mod_proxy without 301 moved permanently?

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache-2.2, mod-proxy

Is it possible to **not send** a 301 moved permanently response to the client when using mod_proxy? I would like the client to deal with the reverse proxy as opaquely as possible.

My Virtual Host Settings: relevant snippet:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /GTM http://192.168.1.27/GTM
ProxyPassReverse /GTM http://192.168.1.27/GTM
```

`wget localhost/GTM`:

```
--2011-09-27 21:54:22--  localhost/GTM
Resolving localhost... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost|::1|:80... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: localhost/GTM/ [following]
--2011-09-27 21:54:22--  localhost/GTM/
Reusing existing connection to localhost:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
```

Answer (score 1):

Apache doesn't generate 301s for any reason unless you tell it to with a `RewriteRule ... [R=301]` or `Redirect`.

The server that you're proxying to is the one generating the redirects.  Try setting `ProxyPreserveHost On` in Apache, in case the application is attempting to enforce a specific hostname.

Comment: Had already tried ProxyPreserveHost On in the virtual host. Didn't make a difference. Have edited my question accordingly. I doubt if the backend server is forcing redirect since the wget log finally shows that client is _not directed_ to the backend server and sticks to Proxy URL

Comment: @user96057 Well, that just means that there's nothing that you can do in Apache to stop the redirects.  Apache doesn't just send 301s for no reason, and mod_proxy doesn't even have the capability to send them itself.  What's the server that you're proxying to?  And what's the exact new `Location:` header sent in the redirect?

Comment: the response header has same location as the request URI. What could be causing the redirect? There is no RewriteRule or Redirect in the whole apache2 folder.

Comment: No, it added a trailing slash.  Like I said, it's not Apache.  The application you're proxying to apparently wants a trailing slash.